# Azure Service Bus scheduled message arriving too late

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using ASB Topics. I'm connecting the service by using Microsoft .NET ServiceBus nuget (namespace `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core`)

When a message arrive, my consumer either handles it and release the message or resending it to the topic with a delay.

The problem is that when the delay is less than 15 seconds, sometimes the message only arrive after 15 seconds.

e.g setting the delay to 3s or 10s usually works fine, but some of the messages arrive only after 15s (in both 3s or 10s cases).
When setting the delay to 20 seconds it works just fine with no exceptions.

It's for sure not load on the consumer because in some cases it was idle during the wait time.

I tried using `prefetchCount` but it had no effect.

I wanted to track the scheduled message in Azure UI but it seems that this option available for queues (not topics) only.

Any idea why is that happening and what can I do? thanks!

Comment: How are you collecting the messages? We need some actual code to be able to help.

Comment: using .NET ServiceBus nuget. updated answer as well, thanks

Comment: You still haven't given us anything usable. Aside from the fact there is no such Nuget package as `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core`, you still need to give us CODE.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core is the namespace. they have a few so i mentioned which one i'm using.
The whole fetching/sending process is done by the nuget, my code only register my handler:
`_receiverClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, options);`

Comment: I agree with @DavidG. The details of **how** you set up your receiving code matter. What's your connectivity? What tier are you using? What region? Is your receiver in Azure? If yes, how is it hosted? Coming to a doctor and stating you have a pain somewhere there is not enough to get a treatment. If you've went so far to ask the question, add a step for those that want to help to be able to do so. Cheers.

Comment: thanks guys really appreciate your help.
I'm using premium tier, my receiver runs in azure k8s. i'm quite sure this number `15s` is defined somewhere to delay messages in certain cases.
was wondering if someone knows about this or has other explanation that can help me stabilize the behavior. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using premium tier, my receiver runs in azure k8s. i'm quite sure
> this number 15s is defined somewhere to delay messages in certain
> cases. was wondering if someone knows about this.

You can queue or subject messages for later processing; for example, you can plan a job to be ready for processing by a system at a specific time. This functionality allows for the creation of a dependable distributed time-based scheduler.

*Scheduled messages do not appear in the queue until the enqueue time has passed. Scheduled messages can be cancelled before that time. The communication is deleted when you cancel it.*

You can use any of our clients to schedule messages in one of two ways:

Use the standard send API, but before sending, set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property on the message.

Pass both the standard message and the planned time to the schedule message API. This will return the SequenceNumber of the planned message, which you can use to cancel it later if necessary.

For more information please refer the below links:

MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:- [***Scheduled messages***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages) &  [***Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2)